# SQL query order by time asc doesn't work

Tags: sql, time, sql-order-by

```
SELECT time,
       null as postid,
       designid,
       custid 
FROM approveddesign 
WHERE designerid='abc@gmail.com' 
UNION 
SELECT time,
       postid,
       null as designid,
       null as custid 
FROM applycontest
WHERE approval='approved' and designerid='abc@gmail.com' 
ORDER BY 'time' ASC
```

Sort by time is not working as time column has numeric values only.

Comment: Please Resove it ASAP

Comment: Which database is that? Please let us know ASAP

Comment: `'time'` is a string constant, not a column name.

Answer (score 1):

Remove quotes around the col name in `ORDER BY` clause.

```
[...] ORDER BY time ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `'time'` to `time` to be `ORDER BY time ASC`

Answer (score 0):

> A sort column can be specified as a name or column alias, or a nonnegative integer representing the position of the name or alias in the select list.

If you really want to order all the result use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT time,
           null as postid,
           designid,
           custid 
    FROM approveddesign 
    WHERE designerid='abc@gmail.com' 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT time,
           postid,
           null as designid,
           null as custid 
    FROM applycontest
    WHERE approval='approved' AND designerid='abc@gmail.com' 
    ) t
ORDER BY 1
```

I also change `UNION` to `UNION ALL` for a better performance, but it will not remove duplicate rows, If you want to remove those duplicate rows too, I suggest you to add `DISTINCT` after `SELECT` like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM (
    ...
    ) t
ORDER BY time
```